# reflection and pattern matching in F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to create primitive values given a Type in F#. The code is as given below but it does not work. I would appreciate all the help and thanks in advance.

```
open System

let getvalue (t: Type) (v: string) : obj =
    match box t with
    | :? int    ->  let r = (int) v
                    box r
    | :? byte   ->  let r = (byte) v
                    box r
    | :? sbyte  ->  let r = (sbyte) v
                    box r
    | :? int16  ->  let r = (int16) v
                    box r
    | :? uint32 ->  let r = (uint32) v
                    box r
    | :? int64 ->   let r = (int64) v
                    box r
    | :? uint64 ->  let r = (uint64) v
                    box r
    | :? double ->  let r = (double) v
                    box r
    | :? float32 -> let r = (float32) v
                    box r
    | :? decimal -> let r = (decimal) v
                    box r
    | :? char ->    let r = (char) v
                    box r
    | :? string -> v :> obj
    | _ -> 
            let s = sprintf "Error unknown type %A" t
            raise (ApplicationException(s))
```

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Also, how does it use reflection?

Comment: It just does not fall into any of the patterns.

Comment: When you ask questions, don't ever write - "it doesn't work".  Clearly explain the problem and the desired behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `t` is *always* a `Type` value, it will *never* be of the type `int`, `byte`, `decimal`, etc. This is the reason the function always raises an exception; those other matches can never be true.

Instead, you'll have to compare `t` to `typeof<int>`, `typeof<byte>`, etc. However, you can't use a *constant pattern* for that, because `typeof<int>`, `typeof<byte>`, etc. aren't constants.

Instead, you can use an `if .. elif .. else` expression:

```
open System

let getValue (t: Type) (v: string) : obj =
    if t = typeof<int> then box ((int) v)
    elif t = typeof<byte> then box ((byte) v)
    elif t = typeof<sbyte> then box ((sbyte) v)
    elif t = typeof<int16> then box ((int16) v)
    elif t = typeof<uint32> then box ((uint32) v)
    elif t = typeof<int64> then box ((int64) v)
    elif t = typeof<uint64> then box ((uint64) v)
    elif t = typeof<double> then box ((double) v)
    elif t = typeof<float32> then box ((float32) v)
    elif t = typeof<decimal> then box ((decimal) v)
    elif t = typeof<char> then box ((char) v)
    elif t = typeof<string> then v :> obj
    else 
        let s = sprintf "Error unknown type %A" t
        raise (ApplicationException(s))
```

If you *really* want to use pattern matching, you could consider hiding this behind an [active pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx), but personally, I don't think it would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 5):

No need to reinvent the wheel, use [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you're so inclined, then you can write a wrapper around that to let the compiler determine the types automatically.

```
let inline getValue<'a> (s:string) = // limit to string only if desired
  System.Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof<'a>) :?> 'a

let x = getValue "1" + 1.2   // no need to explicitly state "float" anywhere here
printfn "%A" x                    // 2.2
```